# ReferenceError: db is not defined"

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

I am trying to run some Js code from Java using the following code:

```
public void mapReduceScript()
    {
        try{
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( CoreConfigModel.get("com.dice.api.mongo.host") , Integer.parseInt(CoreConfigModel.get("com.dice.api.mongo.port")));
        // Now connect to your databases
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "tracking" );
         System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
        boolean auth = db.authenticate(CoreConfigModel.get("mongo.username"), CoreConfigModel.get("mongo.password").toCharArray() );
         System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
         ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader();
         InputStream reduceStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/data/mapReduceFunctionsByGroupIdIterative.js");
         String reduce = IOUtils.toString(reduceStream, "UTF-8");
         db.eval(reduce, new BasicDBObject("nolock", true));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

and here are the contents of `mapReduceFunctionsByGroupIdIterative.js`

```
 function mapFunction() {
    if (!this.eventdata.Viewed || this.eventdata.Viewed.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var key = this.groupid;
    var value = {
        Dockey: this.eventdata.Viewed[0].Dockey,
        PID: this.eventdata.Viewed[0].PID,
        datecreated: this.datecreated,
    entityid: this.entityid
    };
    emit(key, value);
}

function reduceFunction(key, values) {
    function merge(target, firstSource) { 'use strict';
        if (target === undefined || target === null)
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');

        var to = Object(target);

        var hasPendingException = false;
        var pendingException;

        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var nextSource = arguments[i];
            if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null)
                continue;

            var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
            for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
                var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
                try {
                    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
                    if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable)
                        to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
                } catch (e) {
                    if (!hasPendingException) {
                        hasPendingException = true;
                    pendingException = e;
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasPendingException)
            throw pendingException;
        }
        return to;
    }

    var mostRecentViews = {
        Dockey: {},
        PID: {}
    };

    values.forEach(function (value) {
        var key = value.Dockey ? 'Dockey' : 'PID';
        var reducedValue = {
            profileid: value[key],
            datecreated: value.datecreated,
        entityid: value.entityid
        };
        if (!(value[key] in this[key]) ||
                new Date(value.datecreated) > new Date(this[key][value[key]].datecreated)) {
            this[key][value[key]] = reducedValue;
        }
    }, mostRecentViews);

    var reducedObject = merge({}, mostRecentViews.Dockey, mostRecentViews.PID);

    return reducedObject;
}

function finalizeFunction(key, reducedValue) {
    var finalizedObject = Object.keys(reducedValue).map(function (key, index, array) {
        return reducedValue[key];
    });

    return finalizedObject;
}

var lastrundate = db.TRACKING_DATA.findOne({'_id': 'lastruntimeGroup'}).lastruntime;

db.TRACKING_DATA.mapReduce(mapFunction,
                            reduceFunction,
                            {
                            out: { reduce: "LASTVIEWED_GROUP"},
                            query: { datecreated: 
                                            { $gt: lastrundate }
                                        },
                            finalize: finalizeFunction
                            }
                        )       

db.TRACKING_DATA.update({'_id': 'lastruntimeGroup'},{'_id': 'lastruntimeGroup', 'lastruntime': new Date()},{upsert:true})
```

However when I excute the code I get thrown the error:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined" , "code" : 16722 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

I have two references to db one within my Java code which is defined:

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "tracking" );
```

And one within my Js code which should be run in the mongo shell via:

```
db.eval(reduce, new BasicDBObject("nolock", true));
```

I have run the js file on the shell and it works as intended, so something either around my java code or call `db.eval()` is doing something funky.

Comment: The error is from javascript. The `db` object is not available in map-reduce as of 2.4. See the note [in the mapReduce command docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce). Map-reduce should not access the database in the map, reduce, or finalize functions, which is why references to the `db` object were disallowed.

Comment: I am not calling db within the map-reduce. I am however calling map-reduce within my Javascript

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's the reference to db in the javascript - it's not in scope. What you pass in to the eval function should be a single javascript function. That may be the source of the problem. You also just shouldn't use eval at all.

Comment: ah that clears things, so if it is the case that eval() only takes one function, is there a way I can call a javascript file from within my java code to be run on mongo and behave as it would if called directly such as:  ./mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/tracking  ~/mapReduceFunctionsByEntityIdIterative.js

Comment: Try wrapping the whole thing in a function :D

Comment: I doubt that will get rid of: db is not defined

Comment: Try it. It would make the call resemble those in the documentation that do supposedly work. I apologize for not trying it out myself - will do that when I have time and try to get back to you soon.